# Command line - batch file calling another batch file

Tags: command-line-interface, batch-file

I have a batch file which calls another batch file that exists in PATH directory (basically calling an executable with additional switches.)

```
: bar.bat:
foo.bat file1.txt
foo.bat file2.txt
etc.
```

In foo.bat:

```
foo.exe -t -s %1
```

*bar.bat* executes the first command but exits immidately (i.e. working on *file1.txt* only).

**How can I make this batch file to invoke the other batch file more than once?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the CALL keyword:

```
call foo.bat file1.txt
call foo.bat file2.txt
```

Comment: <copied from Duncan Smart's answer, just to keep it together>
In addition to @splattne's answer, use exit /b in the CALLed batch file if you need to return early.

Comment: You can also use `goto :eof` to return early. `exit /b` is usually only needed if you need the return code.

Comment: I don't why but I am struggling to get this to work, I have tried both `exit /b` and `goto: eof`. Is it ok to be appending the output of the CALLed bat? `call foo.bat > myfile`

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @splattne's answer, use `exit /b` in the `CALL`ed batch file if you need to return early.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (for compatibility with DOS prior to version 3.3 :-) ) is to call the command process with the child (/c) option and the name of the other batch file to process.  That will also do a call instead of a chain, and will even work on truly ancient machines (just in case someone runs across this and cares).  :-)

Answer (score 0):

@echo off

echo WbLegalReport.cmd

i:

cd I:\CFS\Batch\jarDir

echo %CD%

WbLegalReport.cmd

echo %CD%

echo WatchResrAddDeleted.cmd

echo %CD%

WatchRestrAddDeleted.cmd

echo %CD%

What I am trying to do here is call these two batch files in a sequence.

Unable to do so.

help please.

Acutally it is failing at the child script, As the control does not return back to the main script

Answer (score 0):

Sanket, don't call the batch file directly. Use the "CALL" command. See **splattne**'s example.